# Deploying Apache Tomacat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, static, webserver

I use a data card to connect to the internet and then start my web server.
But every time I connect I have a different IP address for my computer.(I check it using ipconfig command)
I have tried to make my IP static in control panel menu but that still it does not become static.
What should I do?

Comment: try googling for Dynamic DNS

Comment: This question is NOT suitable for stackoverflow since it is about operating system configuration and not about programming. Please look for other stackexchange sites where the question fits (and search for existing answers BEFORE asking the question)

Answer (score 0):

You need a service provider giving you an IP. This can be static or something like DynDNS (http://de.dyn.com/dns/).